# Angular Shared Module import does not import mentioned modules

Tags: angular

I have added shared module to my app. It looks pretty simple.

```
const imports = [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule
];


@NgModule({imports})

export class SharedModule {}
```

When I import my shared module into another module it does not see my imported staff. I get error like this "Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. (" ,which means that FormsModule is not imported correctly.
If I import that basic modules directly into my app module it works OK.

Your help and advises are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely you will need to also export those modules.

Typically:

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        SomeModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        ...
    ],
    exports: [
        SomeModule,
    ]
});
```

Also see this [angular](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules) doco...

> By **re-exporting** CommonModule and FormsModule, any other module that imports this SharedModule, gets access to directives like NgIf and NgFor from CommonModule and can bind to component properties with [(ngModel)], a directive in the FormsModule.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems that importing child modules solved my problem,but than another issue arose.

I have also to import child route modules

In my case, it was because I had created a route file in a child module "A", but didn't import that route file in the root module, even though child module "A" was imported into the root module.

Comment: @alekoo73 Glad I could help. If you have another question then don't dilute this one and make another post :)

Comment: It's not quite a question, just comment about complexity of that issue

Answer (score 1):

You have to export the dependency modules which used inside the shared module in order to use the shared module from some where else which does not import those dependencies.

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomerComponent } from './customer.component';

@NgModule({
 imports:      [ CommonModule ],
 declarations: [ CustomerComponent ],
 exports:      [ CustomerComponent
                 CommonModule, FormsModule ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```